# Auto scroll fullcalendar V5( resourceTimelineWeek View) to current date and time

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using Fullcalendar V5. While trying to set the scrollTime to the current date and time in the resourceTimelineWeek view, time only is working fine, but how shall I set the date scrolling.

```
var scrollTime = moment().format("HH") + ":00:00"; 
    
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
now: new Date(),
scrollTime: scrollTime
}
)};
```

Now, it is 09:30 and the time is showing correctly. But the date is Oct 01, which is still Sep 27 on the calendar scroll view.
[image: Time only working]

Comment: `now: new Date()` is redundant - today's date is already the default for this option (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/now). But "now" just sets the date which fullCalendar highlights as being the current date. It's nothing to do with what dates are actually displayed. If you want to set a date that the calendar is on when it first loads, try [initialDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialDate) instead. It may still not work though - usually a view will just start at the first day of that view's range. Maybe start your calendar in "day" mode if it's really important.

Comment: (And in the meantime you could always submit a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to see if you can get an option added like "scrollDate" or something. And, it's an open-source project, so in theory you could always contribute the necessary code for it yourself, if you have the time and expertise.)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on FullCalendar 5.8.0 (using jQuery and moment.js)

```
options = {
    datesSet: ({ view }) => {
        if (view.type === 'resourceTimelineWeek') {
            const scroller = $('.fc-scrollgrid-section-body .fc-scroller').last();
            const [date] = moment().toISOString().split(':');
            const position = $(`.fc-timeline-slot[data-date^="${date}"]`).last().position();
            if (position) {
                scroller.scrollLeft(position.left);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It looks like the scroll bar is moved but then it is reset by something else later in the rendering process.